# Ajax returning 404 error on ASP MVC3 site

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, iis

This Ajax code works perfectly is I'm running the program on my local machine. However, once we put this out on a DEV server we get a 404 error. The site is an ASP MVC3 site that communicates with a SQL database, and the rest of the site has no problem doing so. I'm brand new to Ajax so I'm not quite sure where to look. Could this be an issue with IIS as well?

Ajax code

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/BatchPrograms/PopDetails',
        data: { 'programName': pgmname },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
            //$('#data').dialog('open');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            alert("Unable to process your resquest at this time.");
        }
    });
```

Chrome's Console error message:

```
POST http://insideapps.dev.symetra.com/BatchPrograms/PopDetails 404 (Not Found) 

send                                           jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
jQuery.extend.ajax                             jquery-1.8.3.js:7986
GetProgramDetails                              BatchDashboard:51
onclick                                        BatchDashboard:165
```

Chome's Network error message

```
Name (Path)      Method  Status (Text)    Type         Initiator             Size  Time (Latency)
PopDetails       POST    404 Not Found    Text/Html    jquery-1.8.3.js:8434  1.8KB 21ms
/BatchPrograms                                         Script                1.6KB 17ms
```

Comment: Does the page load if you just enter the URL into the browser?

Comment: Note that if this action is marked with HTTP POST only attribute, then it will fail with a 404 in browser, as there is no routing to it for a GET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try modifying url to

```
url: '@Url.Action("PopDetails", "BatchPrograms")'
```

Comment: You are my hero. This also fixes the problem I was having where if I did a search, then another action, then tried another search I would get a 404 not found error. Changed my url to this and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Url.Action()` helper to get the route from the Table Routes defined in your application.

```
 var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("PopDetails", "BatchPrograms")',
        data: { 'programName': pgmname },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
          $('#data').dialog('open');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Unable to process your resquest at this time.");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Only reason I didn't accept this as the answer is the jQuery dialog does not work for some reason (which i why it's commented out in my post). Right now I have to use `alert`.

Comment: Well, in this case is your component :)